# System of Differential Equation with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of equations:

$du/dt = -u / tu$

$dw/dt = (x-w)/tw - u*w$

In the above system, $tu,x,tw$ are all constants.

I need to find the equations for w and u.

Comment: values of $x,tu,tw$ are given

Comment: Can you provide the constants?

Comment: @Moo  Op said tu is a constant so first equation can  easily be integrated...

Comment: The constants are as follows: $x = 1, tu = 5, tw =10$. I am struggling with using the integrating factor method to solve $dw/dt$. I am not sure the bounds for the integral. I am getting something with two integrals to the power e.

Comment: $u$ has no solution for the given IC.

Comment: @Moo. Yes, I was just notified that the initial conditions are incorrect. And the question is now to just solve for u and w.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{-1}{t_u} u\\
\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{x}{t_w} - (\frac{1}{t_w}+u)w
$$

$$
u = C_1 e^{-t/t_u}\\
\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{x}{t_w} - (\frac{1}{t_w}+C_1 e^{-t/t_w})w
$$

Define auxiliary quantities

$$
A = \frac{x}{t_w}\\
g(t) = (\frac{1}{t_w}+C_1 e^{-t/t_w})
$$

so

$$
\frac{dw}{dt} + g(t) w = A\\
$$

Multiply both sides by $e^{\int_s^t g(z) dz}$

$$
e^{\int_s^t g(z) dz} \frac{dw}{dt} + e^{\int_s^t g(z) dz} g(t) w = A e^{\int_s^t g(z) dz}\\
\frac{d}{dt} (e^{\int_s^t g(z) dz} w) = A e^{\int_s^t g(z) dz}\\
(e^{\int_s^t g(z) dz} w) = \int^t_{s'} A e^{\int_s^t g(z) dz} + C_2\\
w(t) = \frac{\int^t_{s'} A e^{\int_s^t g(z) dz} + C_2}{e^{\int_s^t g(z) dz}}\\
\int g(t) = \int (\frac{1}{t_w}+C_1 e^{-t/t_w}) = \frac{t}{t_w} - C_1 t_w e^{-t/t_w} +C_3
$$

Changing $s$ just changes $C_3$ and changing $s'$ just changes $C_2$. You will have already fixed $C_1$ from the initial conditions on $u$.

You see the answer only depends on $\frac{C_2}{e^{C_3}}$ so that will be fixed by initial conditions on $w$ and choose $C_2$ and $C_3$ otherwise conveniently.

Comment: Just want to make sure: You have $A = x / tw$ but that x is not the same as the x later on in the equations or is it?

Comment: No. Good catch.

Comment: Thank you. Also, I see that w will end up being the integral of $e^e^x$. How do I solve that